# Foreach group items from a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I need to group a big list of elements according to a certain atribute.
Is it possible in C# to do a foreach with a 'where' clause in a list of objects or is there a better way?
For example, I have 5000 records and 3 groups that separate them.

```
Foreach list.item where item.group = group1{
do action one for every record from group1
}
```

and so on...
ps.: I already have the records at this point of code so I don't think Linq would help.

Comment: Do  you even need to group the items? Mb simply `foreach (var i in items) if (i.CertainAttribute == 1) ... else if (i.CertainAttribute == 2)...`

Comment: yes, the number of groups can vary and could be large, wouldn't be cool lots of 'if's or 'case's. Also if I have all of them categorized it would improve the connection and the server.  I already have one solution, but I don't think it is the optimal.

Comment: What do you mean by, "I don't think Linq would help"? Linq has the `OrderBy` method which you could use to group all the results by any properties you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate a larger list into smaller ones, based on a property, by using [ToLookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.7.2). The `ToLookup` method will produce a dictionary of lists, where the key is the property value that you are separating them by and the list contains all of the elements that match.

For example, if your objects have a `CategoryID` you can separate them into a dictionary of lists like this:

```
var smallLists = bigList.ToLookup( item => item.CategoryID, item => item );
```

You can then iterate them like this:

```
foreach (var bucket in smallLists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bucket:");
    foreach (var item in bucket)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item {0} with category {1}", item.Name, item.CategoryID);
    }
}
```

See a working example on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ej4bk).

Comment: that's cool. I will try this and I let you know if it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This basic template should do what you need. You can also use a dictionary to map the groups to.

```
using System.Linq; 

class Program
{
    class Item
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var actions = new Dictionary<int, Action<Item>> {
            { 1, Action1 },
            { 2, Action2 },
            { 3, Action3 }
        };

        var items = new List<Item>();

        foreach (var group in items.GroupBy(x => x.Key))
        {
            var action = actions[group.Key];
            foreach (var item in group)
            {
                action(item);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Action1(Item item)
    {

    }

    static void Action2(Item item)
    {

    }

    static void Action3(Item item)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "...I already have the records at this point of code so I don't think Linq would help...." => answers with LINQ :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to do is to group items of list by a Group and then create another list with each group and his items.

If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
var grouped = items/*.Where(c => c.group == //desired group if want's to filter//)*/
     .GroupBy(c => c.group);
var results = grouped.Select(c => new {
     Group = c.Key.group,
     Items = c.Select(c => new { c.PropertyOfItem1, c.PropertyOfItem2, // etc // })
});
```